# Output PHP Code in HTML, literally

Tags: javascript, php, html, codemirror

My question is very simple. All I want to do is write actual PHP code in HTML, without executing it. For example, I want to write

```
<div id = "code"><?php
echo 'Bla Bla Bla';
?></div>
```

I DO NOT want to execute this PHP.  I want to literally write the PHP code on the html document, by somehow escaping the `<?php` tags (I don't want to remove them).

Unfortunately, when I echo it to the browser by doing this:

```
<div id = "code"><?php echo '<?php
echo "Bla Bla Bla";
?>' ?></div>
```

I have also tried to put the code into variables, and even that hasn't worked.

My PHP code gets commented out by the browser. I can see it in the `View Page Source` option in chrome, but the browser thinks it's a comment.

Please provide a solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using CodeMirror to output embedded PHP/HTML code using the 'application/x-httpd-php'.

**EDIT #1**

I can use lt and rt for tags, but I actually can't because CodeMirror starts highlighting code only when it finds `<?` tags.

Comment: can you show us how you put you code in variables?

Comment: I can use `highlight_file`, but this shows php code from another file. Is that what you can ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encode your PHP tags by using `&lt;?php echo "test"; ?&gt;`.

Answer (score 3):

Escape your code with htmlspecialchars():

```
<div id="code">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars("<?php echo 'Bla Bla Bla' ?>") ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

```
<div id = "code"><?php echo htmlentities('<?php

echo "Bla Bla Bla";
?>'); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id = "code">
    <?php echo htmlentities('<?php echo "Bla Bla Bla"; ?>'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using htmlspecialchars

```
htmlspecialchars()
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question properly then  you can achive it by following..

```
      <div class="test"><?php $a='<?php hii echo "hey there"?>';?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Your solution would probably be to not name the file `.php` ... Try `.txt` in stead. This way the web server would not pass the file to the PHP parser.

**Solution 2:** Other solution would be to read out the file from another php script that does `file()` in combination with `htmlspecialchars()` to the file with the desired code.

**Solution 3:** If you already have the code in a variable and it outputs in a way that you can see the code in "source view", then you suffice by only using `htmlspecialchars()`